# mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm running a cron job in my WordPress site and getting these two errors

**Warning**:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in **/home/geekda6/public_html/wp-content/plugins/maxblogpress-ninja-affiliate/ninja-affiliate-library/include/mbp-ninja-affiliate.cls.php** on line **251**

**Warning**:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/home/geekda6/public_html/wp-content/plugins/maxblogpress-ninja-affiliate/ninja-affiliate-library/include/mbp-ninja-affiliate.cls.php** on line **267**

Invalid query: 1045: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Here is my file. 
https://gist.github.com/amarilindra/d89a0e2b90615e0f0c28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application is trying to connect to the MySQL database without a user (anonymous). Did you check if the MySQL instance allows anonymous access?
Just run `mysql`. If you get the same response, than that is your problem.

Posible solutions:

1. configure your application with a mysql username/password.
   https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress
2. configure mysql for anonymous access (not recommended).
   This is the default, so someone must have set it up with a user.

How are you running mysqld?